# PHP Linking to a shared library in an extension

Tags: php, dynamic-linking, php-extension

I'm working on a native PHP extension which includes symbols from a shared library, but I can't get the `config.m4` file to generate a build procedure that includes the necessary linker options to correctly link to the share library. This is what I have in my `config.m4` file so far:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(myextension, whether to enable MyExtension support, [ --enable-myextension   Enable MyExtension support])

if test "$PHP_MYEXTENSION" = "yes"; then

  LIBNAME=otherlibrary
  LIBSYMBOL=otherlib_some_function
  LIBOTHERLIB_LIBS=`pkg-config --libs otherlibrary`
  LIBOTHERLIB_INC=`pkg-config --cflags otherlibrary`

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_EVAL_INCLINE($LIBOTHERLIB_INC)
    PHP_EVAL_LIBLINE($LIBOTHERLIB_LIBS)
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MYEXTENSION, 1, [Whether you have MyExtension])
  ],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong lib$LIBNAME version or library not found])
  ])

  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(myextension, myextension.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

The `libotherlibrary` library is in a standard system location. When I `phpize` with this configuration and then execute the generated `configure` script with the `--enable-myextension` argument it successfully generates a `Makefile` etc. and I can see it doing the test for `otherlib_some_function` from `libotherlibrary` which passes. But calling `ldd` on my resulting myextension.so gives just:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd11fce000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f741e653000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f741ec26000)
```

so no mention of `libotherlibrary`. And the `libtool` and `cc` commands which are executed by the `Makefile` don't include the `-lotherlibrary` option. And then when I try and execute a PHP script which uses my extension I get:

```
php: symbol lookup error: /path/to/modules/myext.so: undefined symbol: otherlib_some_function
```

In place of `PHP_EVAL_INCLINE` and `PHP_EVAL_LIBLINE` I've also tried the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY` macro:

```
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,,OTHERLIB_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

(I don't understand what the third argument to this macro is for.)

I've also tried (in combination with both of the above), including the fifth argument to `PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY` called `extra-libs` passing in the value of my `$LIBOTHERLIB_LIBS` variable. Doing so doesn't fix anything, and there's no documentation of what this argument is supposed to do or what values it requires. So this is just a guess really.

So how can I get my extension to build with the required `-lotherlibrary` linker option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working version now looks like this:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(myextension, whether to enable MyExtension support, [ --enable-myextension   Enable MyExtension support])

if test "$PHP_MYEXTENSION" = "yes"; then

  LIBNAME=otherlibrary
  LIBSYMBOL=otherlib_some_function
  LIBOTHERLIB_LIBS=`pkg-config --libs otherlibrary`
  LIBOTHERLIB_INC=`pkg-config --cflags otherlibrary`

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,1,OTHERLIBRARY_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_SUBST(OTHERLIBRARY_SHARED_LIBADD)
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MYEXTENSION, 1, [Whether you have MyExtension])
  ],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong lib$LIBNAME version or library not found])
  ])

  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(myextension, myextension.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

This technique uses `pkg-config` to find the shared library so perhaps it may not be as portable as @hek2mgl's explicit searching.

The main addition is the use of the `PHP_SUBST` macro which "Adds variable with it's value into Makefile" (according to the `aclocal.m4` that `phpize` created). It seems that the macro `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY`, documented as "add a library to the link line", doesn't actually add anything to your `Makefile`. Instead, you supply a variable name as its third argument (documented as "shared-libadd") and later call `PHP_SUBST` to update that variable in the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `PHP_ARG_WITH` instead of `PHP_ARG_ENABLE` + plus a few other changes. Here comes an example which is working for me. Replace `libxyz` by the name of your external library:

*config.m4*

```
dnl If your extension references something external, use with:

PHP_ARG_WITH(libxyz, for libxyz support,
Make sure that the comment is aligned:
[  --with-libxyz             Include libxyz support])

dnl Otherwise use enable:

dnl PHP_ARG_ENABLE(libxyz, whether to enable libxyz support,
dnl Make sure that the comment is aligned:
dnl [  --enable-libxyz           Enable libxyz support])

if test "$PHP_LIBXYZ" != "no"; then
  dnl Write more examples of tests here...

  dnl # --with-libxyz -> check with-path
  SEARCH_PATH="/usr/local /usr"
  SEARCH_FOR="/include/libxyz.h"
  if test -r $PHP_LIBXYZ/$SEARCH_FOR; then # path given as parameter
    LIBXYZ_DIR=$PHP_LIBXYZ
  else # search default path list
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([for libxyz files in default path])
    for i in $SEARCH_PATH ; do
      if test -r $i/$SEARCH_FOR; then
        LIBXYZ_DIR=$i
        AC_MSG_RESULT(found in $i)
      fi
    done
  fi
  dnl
  if test -z "$LIBXYZ_DIR"; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([not found])
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Please reinstall the libxyz distribution])
  fi

  dnl # --with-libxyz -> add include path
  PHP_ADD_INCLUDE($LIBXYZ_DIR/include)

  dnl # --with-libxyz -> check for lib and symbol presence
  LIBNAME=libxyz
  LIBSYMBOL=libxyz_lib_version

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH($LIBNAME, $LIBXYZ_DIR/lib, LIBXYZ_SHARED_LIBADD)
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LIBXYZLIB,1,[ ])
  ],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong libxyz lib version or lib not found])
  ],[
    -L$LIBXYZ_DIR/lib -lm
  ])

  PHP_SUBST(LIBXYZ_SHARED_LIBADD)

  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(libxyz, libxyz.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

Check this: http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.buildsys.configunix.php

Comment: Why does it need to be `--with` rather than `--enable`? I'm not sure all that stuff about a search path is necessary; I'm requiring that the other library be in a standard system location.

Comment: It looks like `PHP_SUBST` is the key thing here. It seems that it's used to mutate a variable, and that the mysterious third argument to the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY` macro is a variable in which to store the added library. But even then, you need `PHP_SUBST` to actually get your changes into the `Makefile`. What a faff!

Comment: Don't ask me! It is just *magic*.  :) It took me some nights to figure that out. I basically adapted that `config.m4` from other extensions with are linked against an external library. Does it work for you? Note that I'm currently preparing something which really nails it down and explains the macros that needs to be used. I hope I don't promise too much! Expect it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. I'd encountered that document several times but never read it fully. So given its description of `--with` vs. `--enable` I think my extension is definitely `--enable` as it requires no argument.

Comment: I need to review and reword that answer tomorrow. I'm tired for today... I'm glad that it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my ignorance, but this *may* be a hack-y solution as I am not too good at m4.

This is working for me as of **php-7.0**

```
if test "$PHP_MYMOD" != "no";
then
    LIBNAME=my_dank_lib
    LIBSYMBOL=my_dank_lib_function_name
    PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
    [
        PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($LIBNAME, 1, EXTRA_CFLAGS)
        PHP_SUBST(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
        AC_DEFINE([MYMOD],1 ,[whether to enable mymod support])
        AC_HEADER_STDC
    ],[
        AC_MSG_ERROR([Uh oh, library $LIBNAME was not found with the function $LIBSYMBOL in it.])
    ])



    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(mymod,
          mymod.c,
          $ext_shared,, -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1)
fi
```

I came to this conclusion after I saw in the makefile the `EXTRA_CFLAGS` was being defined by default. And, the contents of `EXTRA_CFLAGS` was being added to the build statement of the `mymod.lo`.

Thus, using `PHP_SUBST(EXTRA_CFLAGS)` sneaks it in there. After you run `./configure` go to your makefile and see for yourself!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Perhaps this was actually the intended way to do this? I suppose `EXTRA_CFLAGS` makes sense as a third argument to `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY`. OTOH, you're still doing `PHP_SUBST(EXTRA_CFLAGS)`. Shouldn't that be unnecessary if `EXTRA_CFLAGS` is already defined?