# How to load my own libxxx.so in php extension source code?

Tags: php-extension

I was given a `libxxx.so` file which i can't view it's source code and i can compile my c file with the next command:

```
gcc -ldl libxxx.so my.c -a a.out
```

`a.out` worked well in command line. But after i wrapped it into a `PHP` extension, `PHP` showed a message like this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/myextension.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/myextension.so: undefined symbol: xxxfunction in Unknown on line 0
```

xxxfunction is a function exported by `libxxx.so`.

I'm new to `C` and I think the problem is the way of compiling my `PHP` extension, i searched google but didn't find the answer.
I'm wondering whether there is an option like *-ldl* in *gcc* so i can specify that i'm going to use the libxxx.so in my `PHP` extention.
I compiled my extension by next steps:

```
cd myextension/
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

I have moved `libxxx.so` file to `/usr/local/lib`.
My /etc/ld.so.conf:

```
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
```

I have runed `lddconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the build system to link against the shared library at compile time. This allows the dependency to be stored in the compiled PHP extension, where it will be loaded at first use.

To do this, you need to modify the `config.m4` to add a library. You can do this via the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY` macro. This macro adds a library to the link line and has the form `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($name,$append,$var)`. The first parameter is the name of the library; this is the name of the `*.so` file without the `lib` prefix (e.g. `xxx`). The second parameter determines (I presume) whether the line is appended or overwritten; this should usually be set to `1`. The final parameter is the variable name into which the line is stored. This variable *must* be substituted into the output file via `PHP_SUBST`.

You should place your `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY` line somewhere before the `PHP_NEW_EXTENSION` macro in the `config.m4` file. In addition, it's a good idea to wrap the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY` in a `PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY` call. This ensures the library can be found by the build system before adding it. See my example below.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609438/php-linking-to-a-shared-library-in-an-extension) is another SO question that is similar to yours. It has some working examples you can follow. Additionally, I'll include a quick example here:

```
PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY(xxx,xxxfunction,[
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(xxx,1,XXX_SHARED_LIBADD)
],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Please install libxxx on the system])
],
[])

PHP_SUBST([XXX_SHARED_LIBADD])
```

Note: The second parameter to `PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY` is a function for which the build system will check if it finds the given library.